# How to ignore an ASP Identity 2.0 authentication cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Thanks in advance for everyone's assistance.

New to ASP/MVC.

How can I prevent "Remember Me" users from being automatically authenticated when taking the site offline for maintenance? Doing this in the login page is fine, but what if they go straight into some other page?

Comment: Are you sure you need to stop auth? Why not just add a global filter to redirect users to a static page?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Visser. I used a filter to do this:

```
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace XXXXX.ActionFilters
{
    public class SiteClosedFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (dbHelper.IsSiteClosed())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary{{ "controller", "Account" },{ "action", "Login" }});
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```